# Process does not get rejected and reassigning

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a workflow with approval and reject process.
whenever the document is approved it works fine but when rejected
the process does not get rejected and the task is reassigned.
I have used sequential workflow and on rejection i have used code activity
to update the process and then the terminate activity. It shows as rejected 
but reassigns the task. Any Suggessions?

Comment: Hi, did you use Visual Studio or Designer? if you used Visual Studio could you please pasta your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Visual studio workflow. and this what happens at the rejection process.

```
enter code hereSPSite mySite = new SPSite(TaskDetails);
        SPWeb myweb = mySite.OpenWeb();
        if (TasksListstitle == "Request Form")
        {
            SPList myList = myweb.Lists["Request Form"];
            SPListItem myListItem = myList.GetItemById(TaskItemID);
            myListItem["Document Status"] = "Request Rejected";
            myListItem.Update();
        }
        if (TasksListstitle == "Contract Forms")
        {
            SPList myList1 = myweb.Lists["Contract Forms"];
            SPListItem myListItem1 = myList1.GetItemById(TaskItemID);
            myListItem1["Document Status"] = "Document Rejected";
            myListItem1.Update();

        }
```

After rejection i have used terminate activity process. sometimes Its getting reassigning without getting rejected and sometimes it gets rejected and terminate activity is called. I think there might be some problem with the ID.